# How to to get value from Projected List and Map it to other Class in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using nativeQuery which makes joins on multiple tables to get the resp:

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT e.empname,c.countryName,r.RegionName
  FROM Employee e,Country c, Region r
  WHERE e.countryId=c.countryId
  AND c.regionId=r.regionId
  AND e.employeeId IN :empIds
  AND c.countryId IN :countryIds
  AND r.regionId IN :regionIds", 
  nativeQuery = true)
List<ActiveUserDBResp> findAllActiveUsersNative(
  @Param("empIds") List<Long> empIds,
  @Param("countryIds") List<Long> countryIds,
  @Param("regionIds") List<Long> regionIds,
  Pageable pageable);
```

I am mapping DB response to following interface in my service class.

```
interface ActiveUserDBResp{
public String getEmpName();
public String getCountryName();
public String getRegionName();
}
```

And this is the class I want to return as a response:

```
@Data
class ActiveUserDTO{
public String empName;
public String countryName;
public String regionName;
}
```

So My service class looks something like:

```
List<ActiveUserDBResp> responses= repository.findAllActiveUsersNative(
  customFilterRequest.getEmpIds(),
  customFilterRequest.getCountryIds(),
  customFilterRequest.getRegionIds(),
  pageable);
  
List<ActiveUserDTO> dtos= responses.stream()
                            .map(mapper::mapDBResponseToDTO)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

my mapper class gets properties of `ActiveUserDBResp` and sets into properties of `ActiveUserDTO`.
But my final reposnse objects i.e `ActiveUserDTO` objects within `dtos` are getting `null`.

```
public ActiveUserDTO mapDBResponseToDTO(ActiveUserDBResp response)
{
ActiveUserDTO activeUserDTO=new ActiveUserDTO();
activeUserDTO.setEmpName(response.getEmpName());
//set other properties
return activeUserDTO;
}
```

I tried printing indivdual `ActiveUserDBResp` in my mapper class but it is printing `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@Hashcode`. I am not getting any error just trying to figure out how should I map this projected query output to my custom class?
Also, If I directly map my query output to my DTO class by doing:

```
List<ActiveUserDTO> dtos= repository.findAllActiveUsersNative(
  customFilterRequest.getEmpIds(),
  customFilterRequest.getCountryIds(),
  customFilterRequest.getRegionIds(),
  pageable);
```

Then I am getting

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.example.dto.ActiveUserDTO]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

This is the reason I decided to map it to Interface first and then DTO. but after mapping every property  is being set to `null`, even though my query in the DB is running fine and giving response.

Comment: Projections doesn't work like that for native queries. Use JPQL instead, or define a `@NamedNativeQuery` with an `@SqlResultSetMapping` as shown [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/spring-data-jpa-dto-native-queries/).

Comment: Why don't you add  foreign keys to refer Country and Region tables to the Employee table. It too easy to fetch data in your side.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use JDBCTemplate and then map it directly.
It should be already in spring context, so you can make it like this:

```
@Autowired
JDBCTemplate jdbcTemplate;

List<ActiveUserDTO> findAllActiveUsers(){
return jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT e.empname,c.countryName,r.RegionName
                     FROM Employee e,Country c, Region r
                     WHERE e.countryId=c.countryId
                     AND c.regionId=r.regionId
                     AND e.employeeId IN :empIds
                     AND c.countryId IN :countryIds
                     AND r.regionId IN :regionIds`", 
 (row,rowNumber) -> {
           ActiveUserDTO dto = new ActiveUserDTO();
           dto.setEmpName(row.getString(1));
           ...
           return dto;
           })
           .addValue("empIds", 1)
           ...;
```

Comment: I am able to map them sing column indexes in JPA as well but I want response to be mapped directly to DTO.

Comment: @MohsinM Did ever solve this? This is one of the most common issues and yet the developers never considered to provide a way to customizie this stupid behavior. We always get forced to create entitites for simple queries. So frustrating